# Create new records when no records exist with a FieldB Value

Tags: mysql, join, insert

I made a sqlfiddle to explain this simply:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f991/1
I assume there is a join here so I added as a keyword

Summary is I have a table with fieldA and fieldb. I'd like to add new records to the table if any of the values in fieldb don't have a corresponding fielda record.

Example:

- Color1 | Color2
- Red   | Blue
- Blue  | Green
- Black | Red

Since there is no record with Green in Color1 I'd like to add it with Color2 NULL

- Green |

Again the sqlfiddle I believe explains is easist: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f991/1

Comment: @SubinCPoonamgode I added explanation here but again I think the sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6f991/1 explains it best; uses the example I have above and note in the query on the right what I am looking to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an insert-select statement that queries `color1` values that aren't in `color2`:

```
INSERT INTO AddNew (color1)
SELECT color2
FROM   AddNew
WHERE  color2 NOT IN (SELECT color1
                      FROM   AddNew)
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8cf3e/1/0)**